# Difference between Python's sklearn (DecisionTreeClassifier, SVM)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree

I am new to Machine Learning - specifically, Classification techniques.

I have read a few tutorials online and I'm using the [iris data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set). I tried splitting the data set into train and test using

```
train, test = train_test_split(df,
                               test_size=test_size,
                               train_size=train_size,
                               random_state=random_state)
```

Subsequently, I found 2 ways to fit the model (DecisionTreeClassifier & SVM):

```
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
```

Both models allow me to use .fit() and .score() methods. I tried resampling data with different sizes and random states but I am getting the exact same score of 0.9852 with the 2 models. Am I doing something wrong?

Also, is there a need to convert my target variable ("class") to numeric values as stated [here](http://chrisstrelioff.ws/sandbox/2015/06/08/decision_trees_in_python_with_scikit_learn_and_pandas.html)? I have tried fitting the data frame with the original string values and I am getting the same results. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That code is incomplete...

Comment: I posted an answer using the same data and explaining the mistake that you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to use `train_test_split` is something like the following:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#Load Iris data, X: features and y:target/labels
df = load_iris()
y = df.target
X = df.data

#Split the data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state= 99)

#Fit the 2 classifiers
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=20, random_state=99)
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)

dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted_dt = dt.predict(X_test)
scores_dt = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted_dt)
print(scores_dt)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted_clf = clf.predict(X_test)
scores_clf = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predicted_clf)
print(scores_clf)
```

**Results:**

```
#Accuracy of dt classifier
0.933333333333

#Accuracy of clf classifier
0.983333333333
```

**Bottom line:**

In your case, you only pass as `X` the `df` in the `train_test_split`.

You do not need to convert thr classes. Just use `accuracy_score` or `cross_val_score` functions.

Comment: He is using `df` in the `train_test_split` and since his code is incomplete, I would not say that he only passed X in it. Maybe he is calling `train.data` and `train.target`, and `test.data` and `test.target` when training. Maybe not.

Comment: @VivekKumar could be the case but since he said ''I tried resampling data with different sizes and random states but I am getting the exact same score of 0.9852 with the 2 models'' i seems that my answer is close to what happens. Let's wait feedback from the person that asked the question.

Comment: @sera Thank you for your answer! I would like to ask if there is a need to convert my "class" column from the iris data set from string to integer for DT or SVM to work?

Comment: Hello. For the iris data the class is the y. the y should be a numpy array and its size should be (number of samples, ). On the other hand, the size of X should be (number of samples, number of features). So for the iris y is (159, ) and X is (150,4). both numpy arrays. I just tried SVC works fine